# how to get the values of a view in _preprocess_views_view_fields drupal7

Tags: views, nodes, theming

I have a view of multiple content types. I only select the name and an image from those content types so I'm sure what the format of output is going to be. how can I get the field values of view in MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view_fields?

`kpr()` function doesn't work here because for every content type there is a specific name for fields, say for content type A and B it is `field_A_name` and `field_B_name`.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help,

```
     function yourtheme_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
    if ($vars[view] -> name == 'yourviewname') {
         foreach ($vars[view]->result as $key => $value) {
            kpr($value -> field_field_name['0']);//here you will get the name field RAW value and  RENDERED value in array.
        }
    }
}
```